# Model accuracy is not changing from 0.5%(0.0050)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a CNN model for Image Classification using Keras. I am using VGG19 model and a custom dataset with 200 classes and uniformly distributed 90000 training images, 10000 Validation Images and 10000 test images. Even though the training is at 200 epochs, the accuracy is staying at a constant 0.0050. Same with the loss, 5.2988. I am using Kaggle's TPU instance to run this model.

How can I make the model more accurate? Can you suggest any different pretrained models for this purpose?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Without actual code and relevant details, this is really impossible to answer.

Comment: Train Images: 90000x(64x64x3)
Model: VGG19
Classes: 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CNN model is behaving like a random model.

I know this because since there are 200 classes, the probability of getting a correct class at random is 1/200=0.0050 which is the accuracy that you have.

**This happens when you use tensorflow/keras API instead of sequential()**

Since you are using VGG19, if you are trying to use transfer learning, then maybe you have **freezed the wrong layer**.

If you are using API then you have to do

```
model = Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = output_layer)    #which is not required in sequential()

print(model.layers)      # if you are using API or sequential() this is used to check your layers
```

Then you have to freeze the layer required as

```
model.layers[index_of_freeze_layer].trainable  = False
```

---

**If you are not freezing your model layers**, then try to use lower learning rate since VGG19 is very sensitive to learning rate. (0.00001 or less depends)